# php - Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have some problems with executing a simple INSERT request.
As said in the title, i have this message "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined". the first value is an id (primary with auto increment)

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO championnat_classement 
                        VALUES (
                        "",
                        :Equipe,
                        :Championnat,
                        :Saison,
                        :Journee,
                        :Points,
                        :NbMatch,
                        :Position,
                        :Victoire,
                        :Nul,
                        :Defaite,
                        :MatchJoueDomicile,
                        :PointsDomicile,
                        :VictoireDomicile,
                        :NulDomicile,
                        :DefaiteDomicile,
                        :ButPourDomicile,
                        :ButContreDomicile,
                        :MatchJoueExterieur,
                        :PointsExterieur,
                        :VictoireExterieur,
                        :NulExterieur,
                        :DefaiteExterieur,
                        :ButPourExterieur,
                        :ButContreExterieur     
                        )');
if ($req->execute(array(
                        "Equipe" => $this->idEquipe1,
                        "Championnat" => $this->idChamp,
                        "Saison" => $this->saison,
                        "Journee" => $this->journee,
                        "Points" => $this->pointsTotaux,
                        "NbMatch" => $this->matchJouesTotal,
                        "Position" => $this->position,
                        "Victoire" => $this->matchGagneeTotal,
                        "Nul" => $this->matchNulTotal,
                        "Defaite" => $this->matchPerduTotal,
                        "MatchJoueDomicile" => $this->matchJouesDomicile,
                        "PointsDomicile" => $this->pointsDomicile,
                        "VictoireDomicile " => $this->matchJouesDomicile,
                        "NulDomicile" => $this->matchNulDomicile,
                        "DefaiteDomicile" => $this->matchPerduDomicile,
                        "ButPourDomicile" => $this->butMarquesDomicile,
                        "ButContreDomicile" => $this->butEncaissesDomicile,
                        "MatchJoueExterieur" => $this->matchJouesExterieur,
                        "PointsExterieur" => $this->pointsExterieur,
                        "VictoireExterieur" => $this->matchGagneeExterieur,
                        "NulExterieur" => $this->matchNulExterieur,
                        "DefaiteExterieur" => $this->matchPerduExterieur,
                        "ButPourExterieur" => $this->butMarquesExterieur,
                        "ButContreExterieur" => $this->butEncaissesExterieur
                    ))) {
                return "ok";
            }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: what are the brackets after VALUES ( .. your ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write all column names in the first () before VALUES and skip your id at the second, where you put "" .. !!! I don't know the exact names of your columns so you have to write them..

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO championnat_classement 
                            (
                            Equipe,
                            Championnat,
                            Saison,
                            Journee,
                            Points,
                            NbMatch,
                            Position,
                            Victoire,
                            Nul,
                            Defaite,
                            MatchJoueDomicile,
                            PointsDomicile,
                            VictoireDomicile,
                            NulDomicile,
                            DefaiteDomicile,
                            ButPourDomicile,
                            ButContreDomicile,
                            MatchJoueExterieur,
                            PointsExterieur,
                            VictoireExterieur,
                            NulExterieur,
                            DefaiteExterieur,
                            ButPourExterieur,
                            ButContreExterieur
                            ) VALUES (
                            :Equipe,
                            :Championnat,
                            :Saison,
                            :Journee,
                            :Points,
                            :NbMatch,
                            :Position,
                            :Victoire,
                            :Nul,
                            :Defaite,
                            :MatchJoueDomicile,
                            :PointsDomicile,
                            :VictoireDomicile,
                            :NulDomicile,
                            :DefaiteDomicile,
                            :ButPourDomicile,
                            :ButContreDomicile,
                            :MatchJoueExterieur,
                            :PointsExterieur,
                            :VictoireExterieur,
                            :NulExterieur,
                            :DefaiteExterieur,
                            :ButPourExterieur,
                            :ButContreExterieur     
                        )');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the id is autogenerated (ie. with AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql) you have not to specify it in the attribute list.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) you can find some examples on how to properly compose a well formed insert query.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (att2, att3, ..., attN) VALUES (value2, value3, ..., valueN);
```

Comment: Thinks for the hint, i tryed without an atttribute for the autogenerated id. But still have the same error message

Comment: are you composing the query in the correct way?

Answer (score -1):

Exactly what he says above but you may be able to specify the value inserted as Null not "" because those two are completely separate things. Its in line two beyond the example in the site rano mentioned as a source. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Autoincreament as null ?

Comment: Think you very much for you answers

Comment: NP i hope you got it figured out.